# Classic UI | Unable to add or move components inside "Experience Fragment Container"

Tags: aem

We cannot use /cf# mode to add or move components inside the "Experience Fragment Container" inside the Experience Fragments.

To add a new component once we've added this component to an experience fragment we have to switch to the .editor.html view.

AEM version is used: 6.3.3

[Touch UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doYcx.png)
[Classic UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FGfg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe is not updating the Classic UI anymore and it will be phased out in the future editions. So it will be better to use the touch UI rather than clasic UI. In 6.3 one can easily use touch UI. It will be helpful to use the Touch to build the components and then use it experience fragment.